# How to make SUM by ID and INSERT INTO

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have the next question, and table :
[table.op1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qawm4.jpg)

This being my table, how to merge all the data with summing up the data only from **baza** and **tva**.

The output can be in a different table, cause I will delete all the info in this table, and INSERT it back into it, from the new table.

CuiP is the unique identifier of the company, that should be used to SUM all the values from baza and tva. In a mention, the SUM should be made for every company apart and to not be summed with other companies.

> Eg: Society 1 - tva 500 - baza 100
> Society 1 - tva 1000 - baza 500
> Society 2 - tva 100 - baza 100
> Society 2 - tva 200 - baza 150
>  Should be: Society 1 - tva 1500 - baza 600
> : Society 2 - tva 300 - baza 250

Note that the table has over 1500 entries, I cannot make a sum for every company apart.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide a better image of the table, and from that table like create the expected output.

Comment: Sure, I will edit now.

Comment: It looks like you can use window function  `SUM(tva) OVER (PARTITION by denP) as new_data_tva`. Тhe same can be applied to the other column - BAZA

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. Pictures with lots of nulls that have nothing to do with the question don't help us help you. Do show what you've tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your table should hold the company information and the desired totals of the mentioned `columns`. Then use `sum()` function to aggregate your columns by company.

```
create table1 (denP varchar(100), sum_baza(int), sum_tva(int))

insert into table1(
select denP, sum(baza), sum(tva) from table.op1
group by denP)
```

Comment: Hey, it worked, but this is the SQL code edited:<br> `create TABLE table1 (denP varchar(100), sum_baza int, sum_tva int);

insert into table1
SELECT denP, sum(baza), sum(tva) from dbo.op1
group by denP`

Comment: If I want to do this won't work:
`create TABLE op1_2 (tip char(256), tip_partener bit, cota int, cuiP int, denP varchar(100), count_cuiP int, sum_baza int, sum_tva int);

insert into op1_2
SELECT tip, tip_partener, cota, cuiP, denP, COUNT(cuiP), sum(baza), sum(tva) from dbo.op1
group by denP`
I will get this error: Column 'dbo.op1.tip' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.